# MIPS Program Arguments in MARS

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

How do I pass and store two strings in the program argument provided to MIPS?
I have looked everywhere but don't know where to start.
How would I know/store the number of program arguments entered, and what the strings arguments hold?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/MarsHelpSettings.html) explains this:

> **Provide program arguments to the MIPS program.** Default value is **false**. New in Release 3.5.
>  If selected, a text field will appear at the top of the Text Segment Display. Any argument values in this text field at the time of program execution will be stored in MIPS memory prior to execution.
>  The argument count (`argc`) will be placed in register `$a0`, and the address of an array of null-terminated strings containing the arguments (`argv`) will be placed in register `$a1`. These values are also available on the runtime stack (`$sp`).

This setting is available under the Settings menu in Mars.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
I am now able to print the number of arguments and the address of $a1, but would like to print the contents.
How would I go about printing the content in the $a1 address?
I have "Flex is a bunny" in the program arguments.

Comment: You write a loop that `lw`s from `$a1`+i*4, and then pass that value to the `print_string` system call. Repeat `argc` times.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am able to print contents.
I am now trying to read a 2sc 8-bit binary string (0b00001111) and convert it to a signed valued. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958883/mips-storing-a-int-as-a-string-or-char) 
I have figured out how to do so, but need to figure out a way to print the value without using certain syscalls: 1, 5, 12, 34, 35, and 36.

Is it possible to get an int stored in a register and print it without the syscalls?